# Converting Aspect degree to westness using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, field-calculator

I have extracted Aspect values in degree from DEM in ArcMap 10.2 full license.
I want to investigate effect of Westness in my model so I was using conversion formula of  Folded Aspect : ABS (180- ABS(Aspect-270))
But it seems like this works when we deal with radiation and sunlight.
There is another formula to calculate southwestness of aspect yet it gives degree between 0-200 with ((cos(aspect-255)+1) * 100). (( And why 255?Shouldn't be 225?))

Do you have any idea of the formula for converting to "Westness" from 0-180?

My model is not water-related so that formula having catchment area is also not useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

The general terrain attribute that you are describing is called **[Relative Aspect](http://www.uoguelph.ca/%7Ehydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/RelativeAspect.html)** (*RA*) and in its general form, it can be calculated for any input azimuth (*Az*) as follows:

> *RA* = Abs(*aspect* - *Az*)
>
> if (*RA* > 180) { *RA* = 360 - *RA* }

where *aspect* is the terrain slope aspect calculated from the DEM. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/browse/trunk/TerrainAnalysisTools/src/plugins/RelativeAspect.java) is an example of code that calculates the index directly from an input DEM. And I should point out that the equation and code above will output in the range 0-180.